# Can I rely on ConnectionId for security with API Gateway Websockets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, websocket, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I'm working on a project where the backend is built with the serverless framework. Recently, I added a feature using API Gateway's websockets. However, I have my doubts about my particular implementation's security, and wanted to ask how valid they were.

I struggled to build authentication into my websocket routes. There was an authorizer feature, but unfortunately native Javascript APIs provide no way to edit headers in a Websocket message - this means I would have to submit authorization tokens in the url params, which I would prefer not to do.

I came up with a workaround. I have existing HTTP microservices set up on API Gateway with serverless, authenticated through AWS Cognito Identity Federation. My solution was to "piggyback" my websocket authentication onto my HTTP services, as follows.

1. My client opens a websocket connection, and receives back the connectionId assigned to it by API Gateway.
2. My client calls an HTTP route with the connectionId, which is authenticated with Cognito. This serves to let my backend know that this particular connectionId is authenticated. I push the connectionId and the Cognito identity to a database, along with other information. This way, later I can find what connectionIds are associated with a particular Cognito identity.
3. When a client wants to call a "secured" websocket method, the websocket method checks the lookup table to see if that connectionId is associated with the correct Cognito identity. If it is, then the method goes through. Otherwise, the connection is closed.

I found this resource at Heroku on websocket safety which recommends a similar, but not quite identical process: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websocket-security

It recommends the following:

> "So, one pattern we’ve seen that seems to solve the WebSocket authentication problem well is a  “ticket”-based authentication system. Broadly speaking, it works like this:
>
> When the client-side code decides to open a WebSocket, it contacts the HTTP server to obtain   an authorization “ticket”.
>
> The server generates this ticket. It typically contains some sort of user/account ID, the IP   of the client requesting the ticket, a timestamp, and any other sort of internal record
>   keeping you might need.
>
> The server stores this ticket (i.e. in a database or cache), and also returns it to the client.
>
> The client opens the WebSocket connection, and sends along this “ticket” as part of an initial handshake.
>
> The server can then compare this ticket, check source IPs, verify that the ticket hasn’t been re-used and hasn’t expired, and do any other sort of permission checking. If all goes well, the WebSocket connection is now verified."

As far as I can tell, my method are heroku's are similar in that they both use an HTTP method to authenticate, but differ because

1) Heroku's method checks for authentication upon opening, while mine checks afterwards
2) Heroku's method requires generating and storing secure tokens

I don't want to send authorization over the websocket, because I'd have to store it in url params, and I also do not want to generate and store tokens, so I went with my method.

However, I have a couple of doubts about my method as well.

1) Because I don't check authorization on websocket open, in theory this approach is vulnerable to a dDos attack, where an attacker simply opens as many sockets as they can. My assumption here is that the responsibility falls on API Gateway to prevent, with its Leaky Bucket algorithm.

2) My strategy hinges on the connectionId being secure. If an attacker were able to spoof this connectionId, then my strategy would no longer work. I assume this connectionId is issued internally within API Gateway to mark specific connections, and should not be vulnerable as a result. However, I wanted to double check if this was the case.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into JWT's. It was kind of created for this purpose where you need to have some way to authenticate client-side requests without exposing credentials. It is fully self contained and allows you to not make a request to a database everytime you make a request to validate the user making the request: https://jwt.io/

JWT's are very easy to implement in Serverless and attach to a web socket connection request. You can then do something like add the user IP address to the payload of the JWT and validate that at request time to ensure that the user is 100% validated.